# For a finite locally free morphism $f : X=\operatorname{Spec} B \to Y=\operatorname{Spec}A$, if $rk(f_{*}\mathcal{O}_X)=r$, then $rank_AB=r$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is a locally ringed space and $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, then we define the *fiber $\mathcal{F}(x)$ of $\mathcal{F}$ in $x$* by

$$ \mathcal{F}(x) := \mathcal{F}_{x}/\mathbb{m}_x\mathcal{F}_x = \mathcal{F}_x \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}\kappa(x) .$$

Let $X$ be a scheme and let $\mathcal{F}$ be an $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-module of finite type. Then we define the *rank of $\mathcal{F}$* as the function

$$ \operatorname{rk}(\mathcal{F}) : X \to \mathbb{N}_0 , x \mapsto \operatorname{rk}_x(\mathcal{F}):=\operatorname{dim}_{\kappa(x)}\mathcal{F}(x).$$

Let $ f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes. Then $f$ is called  *finite locally free* if $f$ satisfies following equivalent conditions ( C.f. Gortz's Algebraic Geometry Prop. 12.19 ) :

(i) $f$ is affine and $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is a finite locally free $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module.

(ii) $f$ is finite, flat, and of finite presentation.

(iii) For all open affine subsets $V=\operatorname{Spec}A$ of $Y$ the inverse image $f^{-1}(V)$ is affine, say $f^{-1}(V)=\operatorname{Spec}B$, and the $A$-algebra $B$ is a finite projective $A$-module.

Now consider a finite locally free morphism $f : X:=\operatorname{Spec}B  \to Y:=\operatorname{Spec}A$ of affine schemes where $A$ is a local ring. Then by the (iii) above, $B$ is a finite prjective $A$-module, so that $B$ is finite free $A$-module.

**Q.** **My question is,** if the function $\operatorname{rk}(f_*\mathcal{O}_X)=r$ (constant), then $\operatorname{rank}_AB=r$? I don't know how to tackle this problem.

Note next theorem ( Gortz's Algebraic Geoemtry Corollary 7.41 )

> Corollary 7.41. Let $X=\operatorname{Spec}A$ be an affine scheme and let $M$ be an $A$-module. Then the following assertions are equivalent.
> (i) $\tilde{M}$ is a locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$-module of finite type.
> (ii) $M$ is a finitely generated projective $A$-module.
> (iii) $M$ is a flat $A$-module of finite presentation.

Can we try to use this Corollary ?

This question originates from proof of Proposition 12.21 of the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry book. Can anyone helps?

Comment: Hint: $f_\ast \mathcal O_X =\tilde {B}$.

Comment: Thank you. In fact, that part is one of the things that bothered me. Certainly, if $f_*\mathcal{O}_X = \tilde{B}$, then maybe we can prove that. And $f_*\mathcal{O}_X = \tilde{B}$ is true by the Gortz's book Proposition 7.24 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** The question mentions that $A$ is local, but I noticed that condition much later and the answer bellow is for a general $A$.

As mentioned in the comments, the answer is basically $$f_*\mathcal{O}_X=\tilde{B}.$$

In general if $f:\operatorname{Spec}B\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} A$ is morphism of affine schemes and if $N$ is a $B$-module, then $f_*\tilde{N}=\widetilde{{}_AN}$, where ${}_AN$ denotes the restriction of scalars. This is not a difficult exercise (a proof can also be found in [Hartshorne] Proposition II.5.2).

Now, since $B$ is a finite projective $A$-module, it is locally free (this is essentially the corollary you cited). Suppose $f\in A$ is not nilpotent and such that $B_f=A_f^{\oplus n}$, then we want to show that $n=r$. If, $p\subset A$ is a prime ideal not containing $f$, then $r= \operatorname{rank}_p(B)= \operatorname{rank}_p(B_f)=\operatorname{rank}_p(A_f^{\oplus n})=n$.

I hope this clarifies any doubts you had.

References:

*Hartshorne, Robin*, [**Algebraic geometry**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/298473), Graduate Texts in Mathematics. 52. New York-Heidelberg-Berlin: Springer-Verlag. XVI, 496 p. (1977). [ZBL0367.14001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0367.14001).

Comment: Thank you. I think that actually we don't need to use the Corollary 7.41.

Comment: Since $A$ is local and $B$ is finite projective $A$-module, $B$ is finite free $A$-module of rank $n$. So $\tilde{_{A}B} \cong \tilde{A^n} \cong (\tilde{A})^n \cong (\mathcal{O}_Y)^n$. Let $y\in Y$. Then since $\operatorname{rk}(f_* \mathcal{O}_X) = r$ (constant),  $r=\dim_{\kappa(y)}(f_*\mathcal{O}_X)(y)= \dim_{\kappa(y)}(\tilde{_A B})(y) = \dim_{\kappa(y)}((\tilde{B})_y \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}} \kappa(y)) = \dim_{\kappa(y)}((\mathcal{O}_{Y,y})^n \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}}\kappa(y))  = \dim_{\kappa(y)}(\kappa(y))^n = n .$

Comment: Is this argument correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I just noticed that you had written $A$ is a local ring. What I have shown is for a more general setting

Comment: O.K. P.s. I don't know what the notation $\operatorname{rank}p$ you used exactly means. :)

Comment: For an $A$-module $M$, $\operatorname{rank}_p (M)=\operatorname{dim}_{\kappa(p)}M_p/pM_p$

Comment: O.K. Thanks !~~